# Why does terraform aws_cognito_user_pool always show as "updated in-place" on every single terraform plan?

Tags: terraform, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

```
      # aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user_pool" {
        id                        = "us-east-1_xxxyyy"
        name                      = "my-user-pool"
        tags                      = {
            "Name" = "my-user-pool"
        }
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ password_policy {
          - temporary_password_validity_days = 7 -> null
            # (5 unchanged attributes hidden)
        }

        # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

Whenever I run `terraform plan`, my user pool *always* appears as a change. There are no changes to this resource at all. Is this some bug? How can I prevent this?